# React Not Updating HTML or State Not in Sync

Tags: javascript, node.js, reactjs

I'm fetching the data from the API (node js end-point). The data is being fetched, and the state is being set. But as the state sets, I see in the console that data is there, but I can't see on the browser. I inspected and I see the div is empty.

Here is my code.

```
import React, { Component } from "react";
import axios from "axios";
import "./App.css";

class App extends Component {
  state = {
    scrape: [],
    loading: false,
  };

  async componentDidMount() {
    await axios
      .get("/data")
      .then((response) =>
        this.setState({ scrape: response.data, loading: true })
      )
      .catch((error) => {
        console.log(error);
      });

  }

  render() {
    const { title } = this.state.scrape;
    if (!this.state.loading) return <h1>Loading</h1>;
    return (
      <div>
        <div>{title}</div>
      </div>
    );
  }
}

export default App;
```

Please help!! thank you in advance

Comment: can you share your response as well?/

Answer (score 0):

You need to set `this.state.loading` to `false`

```
async componentDidMount() {
await axios
  .get("/data")
  .then((response) =>
    this.setState({ scrape: response.data, loading: false })
  )
  .catch((error) => {
    console.log(error);
  });
}
```

Comment: see at render, I'm placing it as a check for loading.

Comment: Yes but you set `loading` to `true` when you receive the response when you should set it to `false`